# FOSRestBundle: The controller must return a response (Array()) given

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm starting with FOSRestBundle. I have added this routing configuration:

```
//Sermovi/Bundle/APIBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml    
sermovi_api_homepage:
        type: rest
        resource: Sermovi\Bundle\APIBundle\Controller\DefaultController

//app/config/routing.yml     
sermovi_api:
    type: rest
    prefix:   /api
    resource: "@SermoviAPIBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

And this config.yml

```
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
    view:
        view_response_listener: true

sensio_framework_extra:
    view:
        annotations: false
```

And this controller:

```
namespace Sermovi\Bundle\APIBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


class DefaultController extends FOSRestController
{
    public function getArticlesAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('SermoviManagementBundle:Transaction')->find(776);

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity
        );
    }
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

> [{"message":"The controller must return a response (Array(entity =>
>   Object(Sermovi\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\Transaction))
>   given).","class":"LogicException","trace":[{"namespace":"","short_class":"","class":"","type":"","function":"","file":"/home/tirengarfio/workspace/sermovi/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":2855,"args":[]},{"namespace":"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel","short_class":"HttpKernel","class":"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel","type":"->","function":"handleRaw","file":"/home/tirengarfio/workspace/sermovi/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":2817,"args":[["object","Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request"],["string","1"]]},{"namespace":"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel","short_class":"HttpKernel","class":"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel","type":"->","function":"handle","file":"/home/tirengarfio/workspace/sermovi/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":2946,"args":[["object","Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request"],["string","1"],["boolean",true]]},{"namespace":"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection","short_class":"ContainerAwareHttpKernel","class":"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel","type":"->","function":"handle","file":"/home/tirengarfio/workspace/sermovi/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":2247,"args":[["object","Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request"],["string","1"],["boolean",true]]},{"namespace":"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel","short_class":"Kernel","class":"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel","type":"->","function":"handle","file":"/home/tirengarfio/workspace/sermovi/web/app_dev.php","line":28,"args":[["object","Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request"]]}]}]

**EDIT:**

"Could" I do something like this below? Or since FOSRestBundle is using JMSSerializerBundle I should not do it?

```
$serializedEntity = $this->container->get('serializer')->serialize($entity, 'json');
return new Response($serializedEntity);
```

Comment: I must say that what you were trying to achieve should have been the one and only way for the bundle to work with zero configuration. FOSRestBundle totally fails to meet Least Surprise Principle.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to setup your Controllers with FOSRestBundle.  The way you are doing it, you must return a view.  Here is a link to a rest controller on github that may help you out a bit. [LiipHelloBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipHelloBundle/blob/master/Controller/RestController.php) has an example.

Also, I found it easiest to use the `ClassResourceInterface` in my controllers.  This way, I return an array, and it handles all the serialization itself.  It also uses your Controller name to generate the routes that are necessary, so I don't have to manually define any routes.  It is my preferred way of setting up the Controller.  See the doc entry [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.md#implicit-resource-name-definition) for how that works.

If you do end up using the `ClassResourceInterface`, be sure to include the following annotation for each action, it will make it so your returned array is serialized properly:

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
//.....

/**
* @Rest\View()
*/
public function cgetAction() {}
```

You might even be able to do that with the way you are setting up the controller, but I haven't tried that before.  Let us know if you go that way and it works.

**UPDATE**

For those who may be interested in using the FOSRestBundle without using the `ClassResourceInterface`, the problem with the controller action in the question is that it does not return a view.  This should work in the action:

```
class DefaultController extends FOSRestController
{
    public function getArticlesAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('SermoviManagementBundle:Transaction')->find(776);
        $statusCode = 200;

        $view = $this->view($entity, $statusCode);
        return $this->handleView($view);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you inject a service (e.g. Doctrine) for use with ClassResourceInterface? With that covered you have my vote up. For that matter, documentation really fails to provide a complete example.
Cheers

Comment: @tishma I'm pretty sure you can get Doctrine using the context aware method like usual, so `$this->getDoctrine()`

Comment: sorry, that should say 'container aware', not context aware.